# Can not get rid of modified status in git

Tags: git

Sometimes when I modify a file, and discards the changes via  `git checkout -- fileName`   Git still indicates it’s modified.  Git diff indicates every line has been removed and re-added, but, to the eye the lines appear to be the same.  When you do “git diff -w ” there is no difference. Currently I to commit these bogus changes to move forward.  How can I resolve this issue?

I am using git  1.9.0.msysgit.0

I suspect this is an end of line issue.  When I open a file with vi -b we see ^M indicating Carriage returns.  I am not using autocrlf because the conflicted files are only modified on Windows.

The command `git reset --hard`  doesn’t resolve the issue.

[image: git problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try -

- What does git config --global core.eol return?
- What does git config --global core.autocrlf return? The values (or lack thereof) of these configs might give you some clues.
- Why not use the .gitattributes approach to see if that resolves your issue? [This article](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) has an example .gitattributes file for a C# project.

Comment: git config --global core.eol  and git config --global core.autocrlf both return nothing.

Comment: Maybe someone else on the team has core.autocrlf set to true while yours is default (false)? With the defaults for core.autocrlf and core.eol, in your case when you push changes you are pushing crlfs, and when you checkout changes any lfs are replaced with crlfs. If someone else on the team has core.autocrlf set to true, they are always pushing lfs. And this could be leading to the diffs?

Comment: I am trying the .gitattibutes file used in the article.  It looks like it's going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Line endings may have something to do with it.  Regardless, running

```
git status
```

shows a modified file.  You can `git checkout` that file again to get it clean.

For reference, the nuclear option is:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -xdf .
```

from the root of the repository.  This *will* make the repository contain exactly the contents of the HEAD commit--**you will lose everything else**.  Please read [the `git-clean` manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html).

Comment: Thanks but git clean only removes untracked files.

Comment: If the second command sequence doesn't work, then you've either found a bug in Git, or you're not doing something right regarding line ending configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git checkout filename` without the `--` at the end of the statement

Comment: I have tried that.  It doesn't seem to make a difference if i use the -- or not.

Comment: The `--` just disambiguates that it is a filename, e.g. if you did not use it, and your file was called `c824ee` then it would try to check out the revision of that hash, not the file of that name.